# Using window.location.replace but page still in browser's memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I have this code in a redirect.php page:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
var secs = 5, display = $('#time');
setInterval(function() {
    display.text('    ' + secs);
    if (secs > 0){
    secs--;
    }
}, 1000);
window.redirectTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location.replace("<?php echo $post_url ?>");
}, 500);

$('#cancelBtn').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(window.redirectTimeout);
    $('#time').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

I am using

```
window.location.replace
```

since I want this page to be skipped when the user presses back from the page it was redirected to, but still on back pressed, this redirect.php page loads and redirects again.

Any idea why

```
window.location.replace
```

doesn't work here or how to skip this redirection page on back pressed?

Thanks

Comment: The redirect page is loaded again when user goes "back", so your interval and all the others stuff is set up again. It's not the same old page - it's loaded freshly.

Comment: try using 
**window.location.href = "<?php echo $post_url ?>";**

Comment: So? Any solution? I thought location.replace means that even when pressing back the page will be skipped and won't be loaded again whatsoever, whether fresh interval or not.

Comment: I used window.location.href = "<?php echo $post_url ?>"; but this for sure keeps the page in browser memory while my goal is that the page will be skipped on back pressed

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: OK, I'm learning it and will post my conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at using the history manipulation functions such as `replaceState`, look at the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

You would then do a `history.replaceState` call prior to changing the `window.location` object

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to A. Wolff and unobf I got it:
In the redirect.php page before

```
window.location.replace("<?php echo $post_url ?>");
```

I added this line:

```
window.history.replaceState( {} , 'YYY', 'XXX.php' );
```

Where XXX.php is the page in which I want the user to land when pressing back after skipping redirect.php. YYY is the page's title.
This feature modifies the browser's history so when the user presses back, the page it will go to is not the actual previous page but rather the page I defined in window.history.replaceState.

Now, I get the page URL and Title from which the user got to redirect.php (I do that with _GET or _SESSION) and echo it instead of YYY and XXX.php so when the user will go back it will go to the page from which it clicked the link that brought it to redirect.php and from there on to the target.

Here is the final code that works. Thanks everybody.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
var secs = 5, display = $('#time');
setInterval(function() {
    display.text('    ' + secs);
    if (secs > 0){
    secs--;
    }
}, 1000);
window.redirectTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    window.history.replaceState( {} , '<?php echo $srcTitle ?>', '<?php echo $srcUrl ?>' );
    window.location.replace("<?php echo $post_url ?>");
}, 500);

$('#cancelBtn').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(window.redirectTimeout);
    $('#time').hide();
});
});
</script>
```